# "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large" in R, is it because too many plots in one figure?

Tags: r

I would like to put about 80 plots in a figure, and about 160 plots in a figure. I run the following commands in R terminal:

```
> par(mfrow=c(10,8)); gelman.plot(output,auto.layout=F,autoburnin=F)
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
> dev.off()
null device 
          1 
> par(mfrow=c(10,16)); plot(output,auto.layout=F)
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

Should I change the `mar` or `mai` options in `par()`? But what values do you suggest me to do that?

What if I would like to save each figure into a pdf file?

```
> pdf('gelman.pdf')
> par(mfrow=c(10,8)); gelman.plot(output,auto.layout=F,autoburnin=F)
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
> dev.off()
```

How should I set up then? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using RStudio?

Comment: To save to a file, do `pdf("filename.pdf);plot(...);dev.off()`. See `?pdf`, `?png` and others.

Comment: @chinmay No. In R running in bash terminal

Comment: @Roman: I have the same problem of figure margins too large when creating pdf file. See my update.

Comment: See `?pdf` and its extra arguments, namely `width` and `height`. On the other hand, there may be a limit on how many facets you set up using `par`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: What parameters would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

If you want many plots on a single device, you want to have sufficient `width` and `height` or  narrow `mar`gins around each plot:

```
pdf(file='plot.pdf', width=10, height=10)
par(mfrow=c(10,10), mar=c(1,1,1,1))
for(i in 1:100){plot(rnorm(i))}
dev.off()
```

Default for `mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1`. Really, `?par` is your friend.

Comment: What if I don't want to save to file though?